# Eager loading entities with raw SQL

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I know that it is possible in Entity Framework (Code First) to load an entity using raw SQL like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx):

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blogs = context.Blogs.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.Blogs").ToList();
}
```

But is it possible to somehow eagerly load navigation properties using this method as well?  I would like to write a custom query that loads a complex entity and eagerly loads its navigation properties (using EF with `Includes` has proven too slow).

Comment: I am in the same situation. I would like to avoid the use of linq and the include method and use raw sql with eager loading.

Comment: The whole point of raw SQL is to bypass LinqToSql and force EF to execute statement you want. The only function EF performs is to deserialize output. Eager loading is LinqToSql feature, it affects resulting SQL sent to server for execution. Can you give more details on what problem you're trying to solve this way?

Comment: You can try this.

var query = from emp in context.ContactSet.OfType<Employee>.Include("Slaves")
where emp is Employee
select emp;


The OfType<Employee> Clause will return only the objects of type employee, which is where the Slaves Navigation Property is defined.


I think it will help.

Comment: What are you basing the performance problems of .Include() on? .Include() changes the SQL statement for sure, but performance should not really be any worse than doing separate loads.
The difference however may be that when you manually load using SqlQuery() EF doesn't track the entities unlike LinqToObject queries and that might account for the difference. You can turn object tracking off and see what that does for performance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first attach the blogs to the context, and then explicitly load each property you need. As far as I know, this needs to be done individually, for example, inside a `foreach`.

```
foreach (var blog in blogs)
{
    context.Blogs.Attach(blog);

    context.Entry(blog).Collection(a => a.Comments).Load();
    context.Entry(blog).Reference(a => a.Author).Load();

    // Here you can use blog.Author and blog.Comments with no problem.
}
```